# Why isn't Universal enveloping algebra graded?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Given a Lie algebra $L$, define $U(L) = T(L)$ mod $I(L)$ where $T(L)$ is the tensor algebra of $L$ and $I(L)$ is the two sided ideal of $T(L)$ generated by all elements of the form $xy-yx-[x,y]$ where $x,y \in L$. Can somebody explain to me why the generators of $I(L)$ are not homogeneous for the grading of $T(L)$? It seems to me that since every generator is in $L$ this shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: On the other hand if you start with a graded Lie algebra (= graded in an abelian group $A$) then the universal enveloping algebra inherits a grading in $A$, that extends the original grading. For instance, $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ is graded in $\{-1,0,1\}$ and this yields a $\mathbf{Z}$-grading on the universal enveloping algebra.

Comment: @YCor how do you prove that the universal enveloping algebra inherits a grading in A that extends the original grading? –

Comment: @nomadd here's a way when the ground field $K$ is infinite, say for a $\mathbf{Z}$-grading. Let $K$ act on $L_n$ as $t\cdot x=t^nx$. So $L_n=\{x\in L:\forall t\in K:t\cdot x=t^nx\}$. This action passes (by the universal property) to the universal enveloping algebra $U$. Define $U_n=\{x\in U:\forall t\in K:t\cdot x=t^nx\}$. Then $U_nU_m\subset U_{n+m}$ for all $n,m$ and scalars are in $U_0$. Thus $\bigoplus_n U_n$ is a subalgebra and contains the image of $L$. So this direct sum equals $U$, and thus this is a grading.

Comment: @YCor Is this $$t . x=t^nx$$ a special action or a general way of writing the action?

Comment: This is one specific action.

Comment: @YCor for this case yes it is clear but how do we prove this is not clear for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote down a generator of $I(L)$: $xy-yx-z$
where $z=[x,y]$. This is inhomogeneous: the $xy$ and $yx$ have degree $2$ but $z\in L$
has degree $1$.

Comment: It might be instructive to note that writing $xy$ is really an abuse of notation: $xy$ should really be $x\otimes y$ (and similarly for $yx$).

Comment: Thanks, i'll give yah the green check mark as soon as it lets me >.<.... Yeah I was reading the wikipedia and just realized this thanks